# Add a color for each row in a corrplot with R

Tags: r, plot, colors, graphics

I want to add a colour to each "row" of the corrplot but I haven't found any solution yet.

My code looks like this:

```
#install.packages("corrplot")
library("corrplot")

df <- matrix(runif(60, 20, 30), 8)

Labels <- c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4", "var5", "var6", "var7", "var8")
LabelColRow <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "black", "grey")

rownames(df) <- Labels
colnames(df) <- Labels

corrplot(df, 
         is.corr = FALSE,        
         method = "circle",      
         mar = c(2, 1, 3, 1),
         addgrid.col = "NA",     
         cl.pos = "n",
         tl.cex = 0.75,         
         tl.col = "black",      
         tl.srt = 360,          
         tl.offset = 0.9,       
         tl.pos = "lt"
)
```

So basically I want the "row" of var1 to be red, the row for var2 blue, etc.

Edit:
[image: Here an example]

Comment: Your example doesn't work and could you provide an example of your desired output ? It is hard to figure out what you exactly want as it stands

Comment: I did add an example in my edit just now. The code works for me, even in a new session. Where does it stop working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like `corrplot` offers the functionality to colour by row.  The alternative would be to build the chart in `ggplot`.  More work, for sure, but it allows the flexibility to colour rows.

As a start of a solution:

```
df %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowid) %>% 
  
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = name, y = rowid, size = value, colour = factor(rowid)) ) +
  geom_text(aes(x = name, y = rowid, label = round(value,0))) +
  scale_size(range = c(0, 20)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "green", "red", "orange", "grey", "purple", "darkblue", "black", "green")) +
  guides(colour = "none", size = "none") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: Even better! I didn't know ggplot offered something like this but I can't say I'm surprised :) Thank you very much.